# How can i handle multiple form classes in a single page in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I basically need to design a web page that takes in multiple input (split into different classes) from a user and submit it and redirect to next page,(i.e 5 classes in a single page with only 1 submit button). How do i approach this in django models forms and views ?

Comment: the easiest way is to wrap all forms' inputs in one `<form method="post">` tag then the `<button type="submit">` will get all data into your request.POST which you can process in your view

Comment: @ quqa123 , Thanks! I did wrap all the forms in one template html and i am able to get the forms in 1 page now. But i still don't know how to approach the views, i tried using function based views, but not able to save received data to the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: well use the standard scheme of processing forms in fbv. Initiate all of the forms with `request.POST` - if two forms have the same field name you have to use prefixes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms